# Insert range using IF formula in SUMIF function with multiple criteria (using arrayformula)

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, sumifs

I am using arrayformula with my sumif function which has several criterion and ranges to expand automatically across a set column (B). The formula below works perfectly:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF('DATA'!$N:$N&'DATA'!$U:$U&'DATA'!$V:$V&'DATA'!$BV:$BV,$B$6:$B&$E$30&$D$26&$C$36,'DATA'!$AG:$AG).
```

I want to make it more dynamic and insert an `IF` statement to actually refer to a range vs another based on certain conditions. For ex,

```
IF($A$6:$A=XX,'DATA'!$N:$N,'DATA'!$M:$M).
```

The formula then breaks if I do this

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(IF($A$6:$A=XX,'DATA'!$N:$N,'DATA'!$M:$M)&'DATA'!$U:$U&'DATA'!$V:$V&'DATA'!$BV:$BV,$B$6:$B&$E$30&$D$26&$C$36,'DATA'!$AG:$AG).
```

Any way/workaround to make it work? I tried multiple times, read multiple forums but can't find an answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Cross-posts across [se] aren't allowed. (https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/138255/88163)

Comment: Noted, thanks Rubén, I didn't know, sorry for that. I believe it's been deleted from Stack Exchange now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `XX` is not named range it should be in quotes

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(
 IF(A6="XX", 'DATA'!N:N, 'DATA'!M:M)&DATA!U:U&DATA!V:V&DATA!BV:BV=B6:B&E30&D26&C36, 
 DATA!AG:AG, )))
```

---

## UPDATE:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B7:B&C7:C, 
 QUERY({DATA!A2:A&DATA!A1, DATA!C2:F; DATA!B2:B&DATA!B1, DATA!C2:F}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col5) 
  where Col2 = '"&D4&"' 
    and Col4 = '"&D3&"' 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col5)''"), 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hi Player0, thanks for your quick reply.
I'm sharing a link of a mockup datasheet I created, as the answer you shared doesn't really apply to what I want to do: 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bOkDDg5svvDcgpr1J82TI58xGNPhscvPFta7Bx-V15Y/edit#gid=317891268
Basically, I neet to keep the sumif formula and want to change the conditions & ranges based on certains cells. I hope the link will help. This is a very limited extract and the real one has many more rows and conditions... Thanks a lot

Comment: Could you maybe explained what you want in relation of this sample sheet? Looking at your data, using IF's and a VLOOKUP should work fine. Is there any reason you haven't considered that?